# Освобождение кэша при нехватке памяти

Tags: windows, winapi, кэширование

Есть программа на *WinAPI*, в которой нужно реализовать кэширование данных. Хочется иметь кэш как можно больших размеров. Если память не освобождать, то в некоторый момент кэш займёт всю свободную память, и начнётся `swap`. Как правильно отловить тот момент, когда памяти перестало хватать, и пора заняться чисткой кэша? Или лучше -- сообщить ОС, что данную область памяти можно выкинуть?

В описании функции `VirtualAlloc` симпатично выглядят флаги `MEM_RESET` и `MEM_RESET_UNDO`. Похоже, это было бы то, что нужно, если бы не ...

> "MEM_RESET_UNDO flag is not supported until Windows 8".

Также интересно, как подобные задачи решаются на `unix-like ОС` ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Залочить нужные страницы в памяти, чтобы они не упали в swap.

Для этого применяется пара VirtualLock и VirtualAlloc

При этом, необходимо поднять размер рабочего набора для вашего приложения.

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно отловить тот момент, когда памяти перестало хватать, и пора заняться чисткой кэша?

Можно в любой момент вызвать `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` и посмотреть на значение:

```
x = min( MEMORYSTATUSEX::ullAvailPhys, MEMORYSTATUSEX::ullAvailVirtual )
```

**ullAvailPhys** - это объем доступной физической памяти. Вы видите его в диспетчере задач, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ullAvailVirtual** - это ограничитель для 32-битного процесса (если Вы хотите поддерживать [архитектуру `x86-64`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64))

Для того, чтобы система не уходила в своп, можно завести специальную пороговую константу `FREE_SIZE`, значение которой, к примеру - `300MB`, должно всегда превышать или быть равным значению `x`.

Можно поставить триггер в точке, где у Вас выделяется очередная порция данных и в зависимости от текущего значения `x`: **расширять** кэш на эту порцию, либо его **сокращать** (например: за счет устаревших данных кэша, если у Вас это предусмотрено).

Но я бы рекомендовал эту процедуру повесить на таймер, т.к. память может быть занята/освобождена и другими процессами, т.е. нужно понимать, что не только Ваше приложение влияет на текущее значение `x`.